# Is it possible to select a function from a large number of modules based off a variable (not using if, there are too many variations)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing an HR calculation program and the tax/benefits calculations are vastly different for each country so I have separate modules for each country, e.g. `USA_HR_Functions.py`, `Japan_HR_Functions.py`, etc. (there are 36 in total).

In each module, I have functions (with the same name) - salary, tax, benefits, etc.

From this, I am writing a loop that goes through each employee and checking their information to determine the calculations to use, e.g.

- `employee_1` is in Japan, therefore it will use `Japan_HR_Functions.salary()`, `Japan_HR_Functions.tax()`, etc.
- `employee_2` is in USA, therefore it will use `USA_HR_Functions.salary()`, `USA_HR_Functions.tax()`, etc.

I already have everything written out and it works if I do one country at a time. Meaning everything uses functions from one module. I want to loop through all the employees in one go.

Answer (score 2):

The OO way would be to create (possibly abstract) class(es) for employee (and other business objectes) management declaring all the methods used to compute salary, tax, benefits, etc.

Then in each module you define implementation classes specialized for that country (or group of countries).

One this is done, you can loop over employees through the base class, and the OO magic will select the proper operations.

A simply implementation to be able the create the employee objects would be to have a map of the implementation classes indexed by the country name.

Depending on the complexity of your real use case, this can be overkill or the most maintainable way...

Comment: I've stated an answer kind of similair to this below, but how would you implement the `string (coutry) to object` part? Or would you change the entire structure. This is not my question but I'm kind of curious myself now.

Answer (score 1):

While Jay's suggestion would work for one function I'd not recommend using it as you have to do such setup for every single function (Salary, tax etc.).

I would use this setup:

```
countries = ["japan", "USA"]
stringToCountry = {
    "japan": Japan(),
    "USA": USA(),
}

for country in countries:
    countryObj = stringToCountry.get(country)
    salary = countryObj.salary(4)
```

This way you can loop through all countries using the string with the `get` function from the dict.
I have made objects like so:

```
class Japan:
    def salary(self, value):
        return 2 * value


class USA:
    def salary(self, value):
        return 3 * value
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to map countries to functions:

```
country_to_salary = {
    'Japan': Japan_HR_Functions.salary,
    'USA':   USA_HR_Functions.salary,
    .
    .
    }

#Applying the dictionary
country_to_salary['Japan']()
# Runs Japan_HR_Functions.salary()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case is more satisfying to use `importlib` module **for avoid manual import** of each module and adding it into the dictionary, also manually.

let's say: your modules are placed into `./salary_lib/`

```
import importlib

countries = ["Japan", "USA"]
for employer_from countries:
    module = importlib.import_module(
        f"salary_lib.{ employer_from }_HR_Functions"
    )
    salary_func = getattr(module, 'salary', None) # in case if function stays in module level
    if salary_func:
        employer_salary = salary(6000)
```

In case if in side of the module is an class declaration then in `getattr` you need to pass a class name and after work with your class